# area 51 proposals should cost a small amount of rep to start

Tags: feature-request, area-51

In order to prevent stupid proposals and proposals that are unlikely to *ever* get the required number of users (ex: Pokemon) I think that to start a proposal on StackOverflow should cost the amount of rep that 5 follows gives you (IIRC it would be 5 rep * users = 25 rep).

This also prevents users who just reached the proposal starting amount from starting unlimited proposals.

Comment: Something tells me you anticipated the down-votes...

Comment: You can only start one new proposal per day, unless you have sock puppets.

Answer (score 10):

You answer to yourself. "Stupid proposals which are unlikely to ever get the required number of users".

So what is the problem, then? Just let users decide what they want or not. Just because you don't like Pokemons doesn't prevent the mark from having millions of fans.

Also, reputation on Area 51 is earned from posting good questions. I don't see why someone with a precise idea of new site should be active on other proposals as well, if he doesn't have the capacity or will to participate in them.

Comment: There is a noise aspect to this.  Much as I am amused by Welbog's deft moves (and equally amused by the amount of time he seems to have), I wonder if there isn't a cognitive cost.  Also, the sock puppetry should not be allowed at all.

Comment: @Robert is absolutely correct. The noise is horrific.

Comment: @Robert - noise, ok, but it's mostly at the bottom. If something is really silly, then no one will follow, and it will show only in last pages.